# disable calendar in datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker

I'm using datepicker twice on one page. One is a regular, and another should be only for picking month of a year.
unfortunately css style

```
<style>.ui-datepicker-calendar {display: none;}</style>
```

disables calendar for both. Setting handler on trigger beforeShow like:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function(date) {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css("display", "none");
        alert('fired when selected');
    }
});
```

also doesn't help. The trigger is working, but the calendar is still there. What can I do? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a css class disable:

```
.disable{display:none}
```

And apply this second class in the div you want to be hidden.

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-calendar disable"> Calendar here ... </div>
```

Comment: Tryed:

    <div class="ui-datepicker-calendar disable"><input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker"/></div>
No calendar at all.